# symfony2 - how to add custom client-side validation rules

Tags: validation, symfony, tooltip

I am looking to create some client side javascript validation.

I am wondering how to re-use the one Symfony already has in place (see screenshot) it looks kind of like a tooltip and I think it looks quite good. I would like to add my own validation rules into it - such as integers or other bespoke rules.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony doesn't have a built-in client side form validation, what you see is your browsers [built-in HTML5 Form Validation](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation).

[Symfony supports this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing) by guessing the correct `type`, `required`, `maxlength` and `pattern`-attribute for the `<input>`-tag using the [Doctrine Mapping](https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineBridge/blob/master/Form/DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser.php) and the [Validation](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Validator/ValidatorTypeGuesser.php) information already present.

If you already use the right data type for your field in Doctrine basic frontend validation will work out of the box.
You can pass additional HTML5 validation rules when you are building your form with the Formbuilder via e.g.

```php
$formbuilder->add('range', null, array('pattern' => '\d+-\d+'));
```

For a full list of validation related attributes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input.

Be warned that [browser support for HTML5 validation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) varies a lot.

Answer (score 1):

its not Symfony2 built in validation its HTML5! and not all browsers support it yet!

if you want to get rid of it and create your own validation using JavaScript just use attribute "novalidate" in you form tag.

there are many client side form validator plugin for Symfony2 applications, just google and you would find plenty of them out there, or you could start creating your own validator if its the case i suggest using angular.js!